# Running python debugger from specific terminal in VSCode on the remote

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

Following issue: I'm working on the remote server to which I connect with VSCode. I want to develop my python code (mostly statistical analysis and usual `matplotlib` visualization, nothing too fancy). I used to do it by running my python script in a debug mode by simply pushing 'Debug Python File' button, but currently it results in opening a new terminal on my remote. Now, I was told that we are supposed to launch a interactive job first (`qsub ...`) before working on the statistical analysis. The problem is, if I launch a job through `qsub` it opens me an interactive terminal in my current terminal, but if I am trying to push 'Debug Python File', it VSCode opens a new terminal, which is not in my interactive job mode.

Following the VSCode python debugging help page intructions, I tried running `python -m debugpy --listen 0.0.0.0:5678 ./myscript.py` from my current terminal with interactive job. It worked in theory but it didn't recognize any of my breakpoints in the script. Is there a different way to launch a python debugger in the current terminal in VSCode so the breakpoints are recognized? Should something be specified in `launch.json`? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Debug function provided by the Python extension will use a dedicated terminal.

If you wish to debug in a terminal that is currently open, I suggest using `pdb`.

You can do it according to the following steps:

1. add `import pdb` to your codes.
2. You can add `pdb.set_trace()` to set a breakpoint in your python file.
3. In your current terminal, navigate to the directory where your Python file is located.
4. Run the Python file by using command `python -m pdb your_file.py`.

But I still recommend that you use the debugging function provided by the VSCode Python extension, which you can configure in more detail in the `launch.json` file.

You can refer to [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for more details about Debugging in VSCode.